# Unable to set body & return response in APIM policies, getting 500 error

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim, policies

I am using this code for azure APIM policies

```xml
<set-variable name="newRequest" value="@(context.Request.Body?.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true))" />
<set-variable name="insured-id" value="@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["id"].Last())" />
<send-request mode="new" timeout="20" response-variable-name="id" ignore-error="false">
    <set-url>@($"https://api.dev.com/external/workRequest/get")</set-url>
    <set-method>POST</set-method>
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/json</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
    <value>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization","scheme param"))</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-body>{"insuredId": @($"{(string)context.Variables["insured-id"]}")}</set-body>
</send-request>
<choose>
    <when condition="@((int)((IResponse)context.Variables["id"]).Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true)["workRequests"]["entityStatus"]== 1)">
        <return-response response-variable-name="id">
            <set-status code="400" reason="VOID" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value></set-header>
            <set-body>{"statusCode": 400,
                        "message": "The insured cannot be voided as it is currently attached with one or more active workrequest"}</set-body>
            </return-response>
    </when>
    <otherwise />
</choose>
```

I am taking an insuredId from template parameter of the API operation where I am implementing the APIM policies & using it in the set-body, this will list all the workrequests for that insuredId.

The payload for the POST is something like

```
{"insuredId": template-parameter}
```

When returning a response getting 500 error. How to resolve this. The condition which is there is okay. I am suspecting error in set body.

Also how to check whether a particular string like `"entityStatus": 1` is there in the response of api, because this `https://api.dev.com/external/workRequest/get` url will give a list of workrequest records in array form

Comment: Can you share your trace log? At which point does an error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request to `https://api.dev.com/external/workRequest/get` is failing:

> "message": "POST request to 'https://api.dev.com/external/workRequest/get' has been sent, result stored in 'id' variable.",
> "statusCode": "MethodNotAllowed",
> "statusReason": "Method Not Allowed",

The response of failed request is stored in the variable `id`.
But this response not return any json document in the body.

Therefore, the following expression is failing and an error 500 is returned:

`"(int)((IResponse)context.Variables[\"id\"]).Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true)[\"workRequests\"][\"entityStatus\"]== 1",`

> The message body is not a valid JSON. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Runtime.Configuration.Models.SyncOnlyDepthTrackingJsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)\r\n   at Gateway.Pipeline.IO.JObjectFormatter.Format(JsonTextReader jsonTextReader)\r\n   at Gateway.Pipeline.IO.JsonConverter.Convert[T](Stream stream, Encoding encoding, ILog log, Object conversionSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Proxy.Gateway.MessageBody.As[T](Boolean preserveContent)

Please check the supported http-methods of `https://api.dev.com/external/workRequest/get`.
Maybe your code has to changed to `GET`:

```xml
<send-request mode="new" timeout="20" response-variable-name="id" ignore-error="false">
<set-url>@($"https://api.dev.com/external/workRequest/get")</set-url>
<set-method>GET</set-method>
```

Trace of request:
[image]

---

**UPDATE for question from comments:**

> thanks, I resolved the issue. The when condition I was using was syntactically wrong as I had a response in the form of array list {     "workRequests": [{  "id": 154, "workRequestNumber": "W000154", "insured": {"id": 268,"uri": null, "entityStatus": 1,"workRequestStatus": 0,"entityStatus": 1 },....

It's better to create a new Stackoverflow Question instead of doing it in comments.
Maybe that's what you asking for:

Request body:

```json
{
  "workRequests": [
    {
      "id": 154,
      "workRequestNumber": "W000154",
      "insured": {
        "id": 268,
        "uri": null,
        "entityStatus": 1,
        "workRequestStatus": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 154,
      "workRequestNumber": "W000154",
      "insured": {
        "id": 268,
        "uri": null,
        "entityStatus": 0,
        "workRequestStatus": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Response:

[image]

A variable is assigned with a `true` value of any `entityStatus` equals `1`.
The `choose` policy returns a 400 with `entityStatus` equals `true` .

Policy:

```xml
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-variable name="isEntityStatusEqualsOne" value="@{
        var body = (JObject)context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(true);
        JArray workrequests = body["workRequests"] as JArray; 
        for(int i = 0; i < workrequests.Count; i++)
        {
            JObject workrequest = workrequests[i] as JObject;
            var entityStatus = ((JValue)workrequest["insured"]["entityStatus"]).Value<int>();
            if(entityStatus == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }" />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<bool>("isEntityStatusEqualsOne") == true)">
            <return-response response-variable-name="id">
                <set-status code="400" reason="VOID" />
                <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>application/json</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>{"statusCode": 400,
                            "message": "The insured cannot be voided as it is currently attached with one or more active workrequest"}</set-body>
            </return-response>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <return-response response-variable-name="id">
                <set-status code="200" reason="OK" />
            </return-response>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</inbound>
```

Comment: I checked the logs of the URL `https://api.dev.com/external/workRequest/get` in app insights it has 200 response code for POST method, when the policy implemented

Comment: Can you share your trace log? At which point does an error occur?

Comment: thanks, I resolved the issue. The when condition I was using was syntactically wrong as I had a response in the form of array list `{
    "workRequests": [{  "id": 154, "workRequestNumber": "W000154", "insured": {"id": 268,"uri": null, "entityStatus": 1,"workRequestStatus": 0,"entityStatus": 1 },....`

Comment: Can you suggest me how to parse through JArray, as I have to do this condition check for entityStatus==1 to all the array elements in that response otherwise is there any option that I can check if "entityStatus": 1 string is present or not in response

Comment: @Shree I added code for iteration to the existing answer

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, for me it's fine and sending 500 when response code is not `200`.
I am able to `set-body` with `500` status code.

```
   <send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="createBookingResponse">
            <set-url>@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("domainUrl") + $"/api/Booking")</set-url>
            <set-method>POST</set-method>
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            <set-body>@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("requestPayload"))</set-body>
        </send-request>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(((IResponse)context.Variables["createBookingResponse"]).StatusCode == 200)">
                <return-response>
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>application/json</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>@(((IResponse)context.Variables["createBookingResponse"]).Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true).ToString())</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </when>
            <!-- Return status code if non-200 status from OPA -->
            <otherwise>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="500" reason="Internal Server Error" />
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>application/json</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>@(((IResponse)context.Variables["createBookingResponse"]).Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true).ToString())</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
```